# paypal sandbox account creates 500 Internal server Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I Have integrated Paypal Payment gateway with codeigniter...

For testing I was using the sandbox account which was working well...

but now for the past of 2 days its shows 500 Internal server error and stops with this URL https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

Attached screenshots for reference

[image: console.log1]

Help me to fix this

Comment: Its paypal's issue. I am also working on a web project and paypal sandbox has been integrated. But since Friday its not working. Giving blank page with 500 error.

I also checked with 2-3 other web projects which are having PayPal sandbox and they all are having same issue.

Comment: Same issue with opencart

Comment: Indeed, the PayPal sandbox is unfortunately not very reliable.  All you can do is try again later and hope it's working then.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal is aware of the issue and are looking into it, you can track its progress here:

https://www.paypal-community.com//t5/PayPal-HTML-Buttons/Sandbox-Error-500/m-p/1245832/highlight/false#M658